# azure cosmos changefeed estimator in java

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to implement changefeed estimator in java. But having a hard time finding api for that. Wondering if anyone has a sample of it. Here is the link to the .net implementation of what I'm looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-change-feed-estimator

Answer (score 0):

There is the source code [`Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ChangeFeed/Program.cs`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/6459cec85380689bdfe60e0d8e21018e3811ecb1/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ChangeFeed/Program.cs) of sample code of the offical docuemnt [`Use the change feed estimator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-change-feed-estimator).

And there is the sample code for `ChangeFeedProcess` in Java [Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/.../examples/ChangeFeed/SampleChangeFeedProcessor.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/blob/v3/examples/src/main/java/com/azure/data/cosmos/examples/ChangeFeed/SampleChangeFeedProcessor.java).

The difference is that there is not a function `GetChangeFeedEstimatorBuilder` of class `Container` in Azure Cosmos Java SDK, but it seems that the C# implementation for `GetChangeFeedEstimatorBuilder` also to generate a `ChangeFeedProcess` instance, so I think you can refer to the C# code to write your Java one.

Here is the related C# source code as references for you.

1. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/36444e8914f7224535e7b4ab819d748b66333aa1/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/ContainerCore.Items.cs#L388
2. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/36444e8914f7224535e7b4ab819d748b66333aa1/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/ContainerCore.Items.cs#L411

   [image]
3. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/6f610954032d913eef13727669d0b7e0f061116c/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/ChangeFeedProcessor/ChangeFeedEstimatorCore.cs

   [image]

Comment: hmm. Okay. May be I could've worded my question differently. Its more of why there is no similar implementation in java compared to c#. Thanks